# Unable to Ping Guest VM's of Nested KVM on Vmware Workstation

Tags: networking, linux-networking, kvm-virtualization

I have installed KVM (RHEL 8) on VMware Workstation and created a Guest OS with CentOS 8. I have created a Bridge Network (slave: ens160) and assigned it to the Guest VM. The Guest VM has received an IP address from my home router; however, it is unable to reach the gateway, and other VMs are also unable to reach the Guest OS. Is there anything I need to do in this situation? There is no problem with the default network (NAT).